# Dialogflow Hangout Integration with Card Response

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am using Dialogflow and fullfilment for dynamic response and integration has been done with Hangout. Text response is working fine. But when i use rich media like  [**CARDS**](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards) (Hangout API), It is not working. Can you please let me know what was i am missing or how to use cards for hangouts using dialogflow-fullfilment agent?

[Stack Driver Log Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFsVc.png)

Thanks and Regards,

Ramchandra-Sah GANESH

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly how you are trying to send the rich media as the response? (It would also help if you cut and pasted the text of the StackDriver log, rather than post a screen image.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog about this, since I've figured some small quirks.

The best is to test this first within the Dialogflow UI console, by choosing custom payloads for Hangouts.
Note:

- The first key can't be called **cards**, but it has to be named to **hangouts**
- This hangouts key points to an **object**, not an array (of cards)

Have a look into this blog to get further details. (For example on using this with webhook code) [How to build chatbots for Hangouts with Dialogflow by using custom payloads and cards.](https://medium.com/@ladysign/how-to-build-chatbots-for-hangouts-with-dialogflow-by-using-custom-payloads-and-cards-2006a11b578)